# convert xml to Java object using jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I want to convert XML to JSON using Jackson library. I have tried below code to get Json as below using jackson but I can't. if I tried using json, I can but I want to know how to do with Jackson library.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/convertXMLtoJson",method=RequestMethod.POST,consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
        public Map<String,Object> convertXMLtoJson(@RequestBody String strXMLData) {
            Map<String,Object> objresponseMessage = null;
            ObjectMapper objObjectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            Employee objEmployee = null;
            try {
                JSONObject obj = XML.toJSONObject(strXMLData);
                ObjectMapper objectMapper = new XmlMapper();
                objEmployee = objectMapper.readValue(strXMLData, Employee.class);
            objEmployeeService.save(objEmployee);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return objresponseMessage;
        }
```

**com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.HashSet` out of VALUE_STRING token
 at [Source: (StringReader); line: 5, column: 15] (through reference chain: com.example.springboot.bean.Employee["Skills"])**

```
<EmployeeDetail>
   <FirstName>A</FirstName>
   <LastName>Z</LastName>
   <Age>20</Age>
   <Skills>Java</Skills>
   <Skills>J2EE</Skills>
   <Skills>MSSQl</Skills>
   <Skills>JAVA</Skills>
   <TotalExperience>4</TotalExperience>
   <JobDetails>
      <CompanyName>1</CompanyName>
      <Experience>1.5</Experience>
      <Technologies>Java</Technologies>
      <Technologies>WebServices</Technologies>
      <Technologies>MSSQL</Technologies>
      <Technologies>J2EE</Technologies>
      <Location>India</Location>
   </JobDetails>
   <JobDetails>
      <CompanyName>2</CompanyName>
      <Experience>2.5</Experience>
      <Technologies>Java</Technologies>
      <Technologies>J2EE</Technologies>
      <Technologies>MySQL</Technologies>
      <Technologies>Spring</Technologies>
      <Location>India</Location>
   </JobDetails>
</EmployeeDetail>
```

Expected Json as(Output Excepted)

```
{
    "EmployeeDetail": {
        "FirstName": "A",
        "LastName": "Z",
        "Age": "20",
        "Skills": [
            "Java",
            "J2EE",
            "MSSQl",
            "JAVA"
        ],
        "TotalExperience": "4",
        "JobDetails": [
            {
                "CompanyName": "1",
                "Experience": "1.5",
                "Technologies": [
                    "Java",
                    "WebServices",
                    "MSSQL",
                    "J2EE"
                ],
                "Location": "India"
            },
            {
                "CompanyName": "2",
                "Experience": "2.5",
                "Technologies": [
                    "Java",
                    "J2EE",
                    "MySQL",
                    "Spring"
                ],
                "Location": "India"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Can Anyone help me to understand using Jackson library

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlElementWrapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlRootElement;

@Document
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName="EmployeeDetail")
public class Employee implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private String userId;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName="FirstName")
    @JsonProperty("FirstName")
    private String firstName;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName="LastName")
    @JsonProperty("LastName")
    private String lastName;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName="Age")
    @JsonProperty("Age")
    private Integer age;

    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName="Skills")
    @JsonProperty("Skills")
    private Set<String> skills;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName="JobDetails")
    @JsonProperty("JobDetails")
    private List<JobDetails> jobDetails;

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public List<JobDetails> getJobDetails() {
        return jobDetails;
    }

    public void setJobDetails(List<JobDetails> jobDetails) {
        this.jobDetails = jobDetails;
    }

    public Set<String> getSkills() {
        return skills;
    }

    public void setSkills(Set<String> skills) {
        this.skills = skills;
    }

}

import java.util.Set;    
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlElementWrapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlRootElement;

@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName="JobDetails")
public class JobDetails {

    JobDetails(String str) {

    }

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName="CompanyName")
    @JsonProperty("CompanyName")
    private String companyName;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName="Experience")
    @JsonProperty("Experience")
    private Integer experience;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName="Location")
    @JsonProperty("Location")
    private String location;

    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName="Technologies")
    @JsonProperty("Technologies")
    private Set<String> technologies;

    public String getCompanyName() {
        return companyName;
    }

    public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
        this.companyName = companyName;
    }

    public Integer getExperience() {
        return experience;
    }

    public void setExperience(Integer experience) {
        this.experience = experience;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public Set<String> getTechnologies() {
        return technologies;
    }

    public void setTechnologies(Set<String> technologies) {
        this.technologies = technologies;
    }

}
```

Comment: Normally you'd have `<Skills><Skill>Java</Skill></Skills>`.

Comment: "Cannot deserialize instance of java.util.HashSet out of VALUE_STRING token" tells you that Jackson gets a string element and is told to create a HashSet out of it - without knowing what `Employee` and its properties look like it's hard to tell you more.

Comment: but using json library, I can convert as expected.but why can't using Jackson @chrylis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Change your xml input data , whatever inputs are as a collection group them in tag.and modify `localName` in annotation " `@JacksonXmlElementWrapper`" in java file. Here is what is did.***

```
    <EmployeeDetail>
       <FirstName>A</FirstName>
       <LastName>Z</LastName>
       <Age>20</Age>
        <skillset>
       <Skills>Java</Skills>
       <Skills>J2EE</Skills>
       <Skills>MSSQl</Skills>
       <Skills>JAVA</Skills>
       </skillset>
       <TotalExperience>4</TotalExperience>
<jobs>
       <JobDetails>
          <CompanyName>1</CompanyName>
          <Experience>1.5</Experience>
<technologyList>
          <Technologies>Java</Technologies>
          <Technologies>WebServices</Technologies>
          <Technologies>MSSQL</Technologies>
          <Technologies>J2EE</Technologies>
</technologyList>
          <Location>India</Location>
       </JobDetails>
       <JobDetails>
          <CompanyName>2</CompanyName>
          <Experience>2.5</Experience>
<technologyList>
          <Technologies>Java</Technologies>
          <Technologies>J2EE</Technologies>
          <Technologies>MySQL</Technologies>
          <Technologies>Spring</Technologies>
</technologyList>
          <Location>India</Location>
       </JobDetails>
</jobs>
    </EmployeeDetail>
```

***Now modify your Employee.java class to following***

```
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Set;
    import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
    import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlElementWrapper;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlProperty;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlRootElement;

    @Document
    @JacksonXmlRootElement(localName="EmployeeDetail")
    public class Employee implements Serializable {

        @Id
        private String userId;

        @JacksonXmlProperty(localName="FirstName")
        @JsonProperty("FirstName")
        private String firstName;

        @JacksonXmlProperty(localName="LastName")
        @JsonProperty("LastName")
        private String lastName;

        @JacksonXmlProperty(localName="Age")
        @JsonProperty("Age")
        private Integer age;

        @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName="skillset")
        @JsonProperty("Skills")
        private Set<String> skills;

        @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName="jobs")
        @JsonProperty("JobDetails")
        private List<JobDetails> jobDetails;

        @JacksonXmlProperty(localName="TotalExperience")
        @JsonProperty("totalExperience")
        private Integer totalExperience;

        public String getUserId() {
            return userId;
        }

        public void setUserId(String userId) {
            this.userId = userId;
        }

        public Integer getAge() {
            return age;
        }

        public void setAge(Integer age) {
            this.age = age;
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }

        public void setLastName(String lastName) {
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
        }

        public List<JobDetails> getJobDetails() {
            return jobDetails;
        }

        public void setJobDetails(List<JobDetails> jobDetails) {
            this.jobDetails = jobDetails;
        }

        public Set<String> getSkills() {
            return skills;
        }

        public void setSkills(Set<String> skills) {
            this.skills = skills;
        }

         public Integer getTotalExperience() {
            return totalExperience;
        }

        public void setTotalExperience(Integer totalExperience) {
            this.totalExperience = totalExperience;
        }
    }
```

***your Jobdetail.java to***

```
import java.util.Set;    
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlElementWrapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlRootElement;

@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName="JobDetails")
public class JobDetails {

    public JobDetails() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
    JobDetails(String str) {

    }

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName="CompanyName")
    @JsonProperty("CompanyName")
    private String companyName;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName="Experience")
    @JsonProperty("Experience")
    private Float experience;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName="Location")
    @JsonProperty("Location")
    private String location;

    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName="technologyList")
    @JsonProperty("Technologies")
    private Set<String> technologies;

    public String getCompanyName() {
        return companyName;
    }

    public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
        this.companyName = companyName;
    }

    public FloatgetExperience() {
        return experience;
    }

    public void setExperience(Floatexperience) {
        this.experience = experience;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public Set<String> getTechnologies() {
        return technologies;
    }

    public void setTechnologies(Set<String> technologies) {
        this.technologies = technologies;
    }

}
```

***And use below method to convert your xml to Json;***

```
public static String convertXMLtoJson( String inputxml) {
         String json="";
         try {
             ObjectMapper objectMapper = new XmlMapper();
             ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            Employee emp = objectMapper.readValue(inputxml, Employee.class);
          json =jsonMapper.writeValueAsString(emp);
            System.out.println(jsonMapper.writeValueAsString(emp));
         } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
         return json;
     }
```

Here's what json data i'm getting

```
{"userId":null,"FirstName":"A","LastName":"Z","Age":20,"Skills":["JAVA","Java","J2EE","MSSQl"],"JobDetails":[{"CompanyName":"1","Experience":1.5,"Location":"India","Technologies":["Java","WebServices","J2EE","MSSQL"]},{"CompanyName":"2","Experience":2.5,"Location":"India","Technologies":["Java","MySQL","J2EE","Spring"]}],"totalExperience":4}
```

Comment: Thanks buddy. it's working as per your suggestion. So my XML is incorrect while Jackson deserialize the XML. Am I right? @Nawnit

Comment: Yes. you had defined field as set in pojo but you were passing them in individual tag in XML so it was taking 1st tag and trying to map it to set  and that error was coming ..but now after grouping them under one tag those are able to to be mapped to the set, and I have added one constructor in jobdetail class because when you have parameterized constructor java doesn't provide a default constructor so while mapping to pojo Jackson was not able to instantiate the jobdetail for that a default constructor was required

Answer (score 0):

Could be useful know the implementation of `Employee` class.

Are you `skills` field annotated with `@JsonProperty("Skills")` as capitalized?

```
@JsonProperty("Skills")
private Set<String> skills;
```

Case sensitive should be matter.

Comment: I have added Employee and JobDetails classes too. let me know any config or features I missed or XML structure is wrong? so that I can understand the xml conversion in Jackson.

Comment: Try add `@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)` to `skills` field